# Get the date a file was created, create a folder with that date and move the files

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-datetime

I'm trying to automate organizing my photography folder of over 3000 photos.

I'd like to get the date the file was created, create a new folder of that date formatted as `DD-MM-YYYY` and move the file from its current folder into the new folder.

I was able to retrieve the created date of one of the files using the below code

```
print("created: %s" % time.ctime(os.path.getctime(file)))
```

Which returns `created: Fri Mar 22 17:49:36 2019`.

Below is a sample of the folder. In this case, the created date is the same as the modified date but this is not always the case!

[image: Files in folder]

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `os.listdir` to get a list of files in a directory, then filter them by `os.path.isfile` and/or `f.endswith` to only accept image files. You pretty much have the timestamp code (you can use `strftime` to format it), so it's a matter of making any necessary directories with `os.makedirs` and copying the files with `os.replace`.

All relevant methods can be found in the documentation for the [`os`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) and [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) modules.

```
import os
from datetime import datetime

path = "."
ext = "CR2"

for f in os.listdir(path):
    fpath = os.path.join(path, f)

    if os.path.isfile(fpath) and fpath.endswith(ext):
        time = datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getctime(fpath)).strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
        os.makedirs(os.path.join(path, time), exist_ok=True)
        os.replace(fpath, os.path.join(path, time, f))
```

If you want to accept multiple extensions and organize them into subfolders by extension, you can use:

```
import os
from datetime import datetime

path = "foo"
exts = set(["cr2", "jpg"])

for f in os.listdir(path):
    fpath = os.path.join(path, f)
    ext = f.split(".")[-1].lower()

    if os.path.isfile(fpath) and ext in exts:
        time = datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getctime(fpath)).strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
        os.makedirs(os.path.join(path, time, ext), exist_ok=True)
        os.replace(fpath, os.path.join(path, time, ext, f))
```

Comment: Is there a way to add another if statement that if the file is CR2 then add to that folder, but if the file is .JPG or .JPEG then create a folder in that folder called JPEG Files and add it to there instead?

Comment: It did. You have just saved me hours of work. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `mtime` instead of `ctime` but as it looks from your screenshot and as far as I know, there is no way to get the 'time created' time on windows. `ctime` stands for change time and is more subject to changes than `mtime`. (Detailed explaination [here](https://www.unix.com/tips-and-tutorials/20526-mtime-ctime-atime.html))

What you can do in order to get to your goal, is read out the EXIF-data from your images. They should hold the date and time when your images were taken. If you are unsure, if your images hold EXIF-data, you can use the following script to fall back to `mtime`, if no exif-data is found:

```
import exifread
import shutil
import os
import sys
import datetime

ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'cr2'])

def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS

if len(sys.argv) < 1:
    print('Please provide directory as argument!')

directory = sys.argv[1] # get the directory where we are looking for images
img_files = os.listdir(directory)  # get the files of the directory

for img in img_files:
    date = None
    if allowed_file(img): # check if the file is an image file
        full_path = os.path.join(directory, img)
        with open(full_path, 'rb') as image_file:
            tags = exifread.process_file(image_file, stop_tag='EXIF DateTimeOriginal')
            date_taken = str(tags.get('EXIF DateTimeOriginal'))
            try:
                date_time_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_taken, '%Y:%m:%d %H:%M:%S')
                date = date_time_obj.date() # getting the date in YYYY-MM-DD format
            except ValueError:
                print('Cannot find EXIF')
        if not date:
            print('Using mtime')
            mtime = os.path.getmtime(full_path)
            date_time_obj = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(mtime)
            date = date_time_obj.date()
        print('Image: {} - Date: {}'.format(img, date))
        new_directory = 'Sorted/{}'.format(date)
        os.makedirs(new_directory, exist_ok=True)  # make the new directory
        shutil.copyfile(full_path, os.path.join(new_directory, img))  # copy file into the new directory - it will have the format YYYY-MM-DD
```

This script will read out EXIF data from your images, if there is none, it falls back to `mtime`, creates folders and copies the images into the folders.

Please note that in this script I formatted the date to YYYY-MM-DD. You can change it of course easily. It's just, that the directories in the `Sorted`-folder than are displayed in ascending order, which is convinient. But of course not mandatory.

If you safe the script as `sort.py` you can start it with `python sort.py <directory-to-sort>`. (`exifread` and `shutil` must be installed via `pip install` before that)